# Image Segmentation watershed

Tags: opencv, watershed

My work is to find an individual leaf from an group of leaves in the image. The constrain is the individual leaf i have to segment must be complete in shape. I used marker based watershed transform.

[image1](http://answers.opencv.org/upfiles/14109354304208541.jpg)

I get this [output](http://answers.opencv.org/upfiles/14109356693903362.png)

I created the marker using dilation and erosion to find background and fore ground.

From this image how can i segment an individual leaf? What steps shall i go?

Comment: i think your marker itself needs some revision and what have you tried?

Comment: were you able to segment the leaves?